# How can I increase the loudness of Firefox on Windows 10 over 100%

Tags: firefox, audio, windows-10

If there a way in Firefox on Windows 10 to increase the sound when I play a YouTube video at 100% loudness with 100% loudness on the system level as well?

Comment: I don’t quite understand: Do you feel the maximum volume is too low? Or do you simply want Youtube to always run at 100% volume?

Comment: @DanielB: I consider the maximum volumne for some videos too low.